# "Cannot nest" error trying to integrate mopub + Eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse, mopub

Trying to integrate mopub but I get this error when I try to import the project:
"Cannot nest 'mopub-sdk/src/main/java' inside 'mopub-sdk/src'. To enable the nesting exclude 'main/' from 'mopub-sdk/src'"

Same error in a fresh workspace as well, so not sure what it could be. No help from mopub yet, and tried all versions of their sdk.

Appreciate any advice, thanks.

Comment: mopub-sdk/src itself is set as a source folder. You can't have have one source folder inside another (nest them) because then the search path for packages and source/class files goes all weird on you.